# the word summer is sumatoria?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

I have a sentence, in the sentence appear the word summer, but 
I can not understand the meaning (bold added):

> A single-input neuron is shown in Figure 2.1. The scalar input *p* is multiplied by the scalar *weight w* to form *wp*, one of the terms that is sent to the **summer**.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sumatoria" in your title.

Answer (score 3):

The *summer* here is related to the word *sum*.

Just like a *multiplier* is a component that multiplies, a *summer* is a component that performs addition.

I can see why it may have been hard to find this word in a dictionary, as it's a rather technical term and many dictionaries may omit this derivation. [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/summer), however, lists this definition:

> **summer** (*n.*) a person who sums

In your text, though, it refers to a component of a system rather than a human.